# How do I check if a letter is within A-Z and a-z in python?

Tags: python, string, character

So the word must have two `A-Z` characters and `a-z` characters. I used the `.isalpha()` function to check lower case then how do I do with uppercase characters?

yeah the only thing on my mind is `CapiChar=['A',......'Z']` and `if char in CapiChar: counter=counter+1`

Answer (score 0):

`.isalpha()` checks for both lowercase and uppercase. You should use `.isupper()` and `.islower()` methods:

```
my_word = "FooBar"

lowercase_count = len([c for c in my_word if c.islower()])
uppercase_count = len([c for c in my_word if c.isupper()])

print(f"{lowercase_count=}, {uppercase_count=}")
```

This should print:

```
lowercase_count=4, uppercase_count=2
```

Comment: It misses the constraint to ascii range, if we have a string "FoöB" the code above would count ö, but question has a restriction to Basic Latin letters. So either the string module and ascii_lowercase() etc, or extend the list comprehension: len([c for c in my_word if c.islower() and c.isascii()]) etc.

Comment: Where did you see that restriction? The OP was originally using `.isalpha()`, so apparently they are either happy with non-ASCII letters, or it is not relevant.

Comment: the question was "so the word must have two A-Z characters and a-z characters." Yes the OP used `.isalpha()` but A-Z characters and a-z characters." Yes the OP used `.isalpha()` will not provide the results he wants unless the input string is already restricted to ASCII characters (but that isn't explictedly stated in the question. But personally I see little use for `.isalpha()`. I tend to be more interested in word forming characters. `.isalpha()` is way too restrictive for my needs.

Comment: We don't know what the use case is, we do not no what a representative string looks like, we don't know what characters may or may not be in the string. Probability is that its like most python code and has a limited character repertoire, but that is a guess. All we know is that there must be two lowercase basic Latin characters and two uppercase basic Latin characters.